# Using GHC API from GHC compiled from source

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, ghc-api

I'd like to, within a client program, use the GHC API from a 
modified version of GHC. Its easy enough to get the GHC sources
and build and install the modified GHC, but installing the 
modified GHC causes all older (Cabal) dependencies to break.

Consequently, I cannot use the GHC API as ghc -v says:

package ghc-7.0.3-... is unusable due to missing or recursive dependencies:...

Any clues on how to proceed?

Thanks!,

Ranjit.

Comment: What modifications to GHC are you making?

Answer (score 1):

You must build a custom version of GHC *first*, then install all the packages you need. That way, everything will be linked against your custom GHC, and you will be fine.

Comment: OK, let me try this: 1. install the binary ghc-7.0.3, then 2. use it to build/install modified ghc? I'll give this a whirl. However, does this mean that everytime I rebuild GHC I might have to reinstall everything else? (As of now, there is no modification, am just trying to use the GHC-API from a custom build as a warm up...) Longer term, I'm trying to add a little more source information `SrcSpan` to the `CoreExpr`...

Comment: Sounds  like your broke your GHC build fairly well.

Comment: Whew, looks like its because the latest GHC (7.1.XXX) uses Cabal-1.11 which throws off the haskell-platform build scripts. I just built a custom GHC from the 7.0.3 sources and that seems to work fine. thanks!

Comment: Actually the above didn't really work. [Simon Marlow](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/simonmar/) pointed me to [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Debugging/InstallingPackagesInplace) which works like a charm...